# Portfolio optimization and MMULT for matrix multiplication not giving me the correct answer

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two vectors in Excel that I want to perform matrix multiclication:
[image]

I want to calculate the portfolio return, which should be (30% * 3%) + (20% * 2%) + (50% * 1%) = 1.8%

I performed MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A2:C2),A5:C5), and it gives me 0.60%. Am I doing something wrong????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Jeeped's answer that `SUMPRODUCT` is better to use here.

Just giving a bit more information:

`MMULT(TRANSPOSE(A2:C2),A5:C5)` mathematically performs the following:

```
[0.3]                            [0.009  0.006  0.003]
[0.2]  *  [0.03  0.02  0.01]  =  [0.006  0.004  0.002]
[0.5]                            [0.015  0.010  0.005]
```

Typically, if a formula returns an array, the value in the upper-left most column only is displayed in the cell. (In this case, it would be `0.9%` since `0.009` is formatted as a percentage).

**However**, in this case, `0.9%` would only be returned if the formula is entered as an array formula (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>). I've found that `TRANSPOSE` acts very strange when it is part of a non-array formula, which explains you seeing the incorrect result of `0.6%`.

Of course, this matrix result isn't even what you want anyway, since you only want a single result. You actually need the `TRANSPOSE` to be in the second argument of `MMULT` rather than the first argument.

`MMULT(A2:C2,TRANSPOSE(A5:C5))` mathematically performs the following:

```
                    [0.03]
[0.3  0.2  0.5]  *  [0.02]  =  [0.018]
                    [0.01]
```

And this is what you want.

Again, in order to actually get this result, you must enter `MMULT(A2:C2,TRANSPOSE(A5:C5))` as an array formula.

Comment: @JunJang You're welcome. Please accept one of these answers as correct.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need SUMPRODUCT, not MMULT.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:C2, A4:C4)
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it using MMULT?

Comment: It's not the same mathematical operation. Go through each with Formulas, Formula Auditing, Evaluate formula to see the differences.

Comment: Interesting to note, MMULT will only give the result quoted if placed in column B.  So not only is it the wrong maths, it's invoking implicit intersection as well!

Comment: @chrisneilsen `MMULT` will give the same result regardless of where the formula is located *if it is entered as an array formula*. The reason you are seeing different results for the formula in different locations is because of `TRANSPOSE`, which I've found acts very strange (and incorrectly) if the formula is not entered as an array formula.

Comment: @imaginary No, i never said anything about an array formula As OP used it (and as you answered) it returns an array. It was virtue of implicit intersection from being in second column of the source the OP got the top result of a vector = 0.6%.  All not relevant to the Q, Just an explanation on why the OP got the answer they did.  Behaviour of Transpose is entirety predictable